# Timer interrupt won't work if the ISR is not set

Tags: programming, arduino-mega, c, interrupt

I am using an Arduino Mega 2560.

I have a code in a c file, that looks like this:

```
    #include <avr/io.h>             /* for DDRB, PORTB, etc. */
#include <util/delay.h>         /* for _delay_ms () */
#include <arduino.h>



int main(void){
  DDRB    |= ((1 << DDB7)); // Define pin 13 as output

  noInterrupts();

//set timer1 interrupt at 1Hz
  TCCR1A = 0;// set entire TCCR1A register to 0
  TCCR1B = 0;// same for TCCR1B
  TCNT1  = 0;//initialize counter value to 0
  // set compare match register for 1hz increments
  OCR1A = 15624;// = (16*10^6) / (1*1024) - 1 (must be <65536)
  // turn on CTC mode
  TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12);
  // Set CS12 and CS10 bits for 1024 prescaler
  TCCR1B |= (1 << CS12) | (1 << CS10);  
  // enable timer compare interrupt
  TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A);
  interrupts();

  while(1){
        asm("nop");
  }
return 0;
}



  ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)          // timer compare interrupt service routine
{
  PORTB ^= ((1 <<  PB7));   // toggle LED pin
  PINB |= _BV(7);
  PINB = PINB | _BV(7);
}
```

Which is called from an ino file, like this:

```
    extern "C"
 {
 void foo ();
 }

void setup ()
  {  
  foo ();
  }  // end of setup

void loop ()
  {
  }  // end of loop
```

However, if I set up another timer interrupt (ex Timer Interrupt 0 or 2, the blink will stop happening, for some reason...

For example:

```
//set timer0 interrupt at 2kHz
  TCCR0A = 0;// set entire TCCR2A register to 0
  TCCR0B = 0;// same for TCCR2B
  TCNT0  = 0;//initialize counter value to 0
  // set compare match register for 2khz increments
  OCR0A = 124;// = (16*10^6) / (2000*64) - 1 (must be <256)
  // turn on CTC mode
  TCCR0A |= (1 << WGM01);
  // Set CS01 and CS00 bits for 64 prescaler
  TCCR0B |= (1 << CS01) | (1 << CS00);   
  // enable timer compare interrupt
  TIMSK0 |= (1 << OCIE0A);
```

Now, the strangest part happens that if all the three (or just the same two) timer interrupts are set, and with everything defined in the INO file, it works fine...

```
//this code will enable all three arduino timer interrupts.
//timer0 will interrupt at 2kHz
//timer1 will interrupt at 1Hz
//timer2 will interrupt at 8kHz

//storage variables
boolean toggle0 = 0;
boolean toggle1 = 0;
boolean toggle2 = 0;

void setup(){

  //set pins as outputs
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

cli();//stop interrupts

//set timer0 interrupt at 2kHz
  TCCR0A = 0;// set entire TCCR2A register to 0
  TCCR0B = 0;// same for TCCR2B
  TCNT0  = 0;//initialize counter value to 0
  // set compare match register for 2khz increments
  OCR0A = 124;// = (16*10^6) / (2000*64) - 1 (must be <256)
  // turn on CTC mode
  TCCR0A |= (1 << WGM01);
  // Set CS01 and CS00 bits for 64 prescaler
  TCCR0B |= (1 << CS01) | (1 << CS00);   
  // enable timer compare interrupt
  TIMSK0 |= (1 << OCIE0A);

//set timer1 interrupt at 1Hz
  TCCR1A = 0;// set entire TCCR1A register to 0
  TCCR1B = 0;// same for TCCR1B
  TCNT1  = 0;//initialize counter value to 0
  // set compare match register for 1hz increments
  OCR1A = 15624;// = (16*10^6) / (1*1024) - 1 (must be <65536)
  // turn on CTC mode
  TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12);
  // Set CS12 and CS10 bits for 1024 prescaler
  TCCR1B |= (1 << CS12) | (1 << CS10);  
  // enable timer compare interrupt
  TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A);

//set timer2 interrupt at 8kHz
  TCCR2A = 0;// set entire TCCR2A register to 0
  TCCR2B = 0;// same for TCCR2B
  TCNT2  = 0;//initialize counter value to 0
  // set compare match register for 8khz increments
  OCR2A = 249;// = (16*10^6) / (8000*8) - 1 (must be <256)
  // turn on CTC mode
  TCCR2A |= (1 << WGM21);
  // Set CS21 bit for 8 prescaler
  TCCR2B |= (1 << CS21);   
  // enable timer compare interrupt
  TIMSK2 |= (1 << OCIE2A);


sei();//allow interrupts

}//end setup

ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect){//timer0 interrupt 2kHz toggles pin 8
//generates pulse wave of frequency 2kHz/2 = 1kHz (takes two cycles for full wave- toggle high then toggle low)
  if (toggle0){
    digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
    toggle0 = 0;
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(8,LOW);
    toggle0 = 1;
  }
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect){//timer1 interrupt 1Hz toggles pin 13 (LED)
//generates pulse wave of frequency 1Hz/2 = 0.5kHz (takes two cycles for full wave- toggle high then toggle low)
  if (toggle1){
    digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
    toggle1 = 0;
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);
    toggle1 = 1;
  }
}

ISR(TIMER2_COMPA_vect){//timer1 interrupt 8kHz toggles pin 9
//generates pulse wave of frequency 8kHz/2 = 4kHz (takes two cycles for full wave- toggle high then toggle low)
  if (toggle2){
    digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
    toggle2 = 0;
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(9,LOW);
    toggle2 = 1;
  }
}


void loop(){
  //do other things here
}
```

Is anybody able to explain why it works in the first case, doesn't work in the second, and in the third, it works as well?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that it's not enough to just define the interrupts, there must also be an ISR method with the compare vector...

```
  ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect)          // timer compare interrupt service routine
{
  PORTB ^= ((1 <<  PB6));   // toggle LED pin
  PINB |= _BV(6);
  PINB = PINB | _BV(6);
}
```

There was no error at compile, though.

Comment: `there must also be an ISR method with the compare vector` - that's correct - you have told the processor to jump to an ISR vector, and the default vector jumps to the start of your program. `There was no error at compile, though.` - you have not made any **syntactical** errors.